# Adding new element to tree also adds it to partial copy of tree

Tags: java, collections

In the following code, we create two distinct TreeSet objects.

We assign some values to 1st object, and then we assign a subset of 1st object to 2nd object. We then add an element (609) to 1st object **only**. Why then does this new element appear in **both** objects?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Explorer1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<Integer> s = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        TreeSet<Integer> subs = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        for(int i = 606; i < 613; i++)
            if(i%2 == 0) s.add(i);
        subs = (TreeSet)s.subSet(608, true, 611, true);
        s.add(609);
        System.out.println(s + " " + subs);
    }
}
```

Output:[606, 608, 609, 610, 612] [608, 609, 610]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#subSet%28E,%20boolean,%20E,%20boolean%29):

> The returned set is backed by this set, **so changes in the returned set are reflected in this set, and vice-versa**. The returned set supports all optional set operations that this set supports.

Of course, if you don't want the changes in the returned set to reflect in the original set, just make a copy of subset:

```
subs = new TreeSet<>(s.subSet(608, true, 611, true));
```

Note that, your original code has an *unchecked cast* operation. You should not cast to `TreeSet`, but `TreeSet<Integer>`:

```
subs = (TreeSet<Integer>)s.subSet(608, true, 611, true);
```

Comment: +1 for telling what is the reason, It would be great If you tell whats the remedy :)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ As I remember, this code is from an SCJP book, I think Kathy Sierra ;)